# Python Float Division Not Exact

Tags: python, floating-point, division

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python float - str - float weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778368/python-float-str-float-weirdness)

Python float division does not appear to have accurate results. Can someone explain why?

```
>>>3.0/5
0.59999999999999998
```

Comment: must be one of the most commonly asked questions on SO in every conceivable language that supports floating point. Pity a search didn't find anything...oh wait! : http://www.google.com.au/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=site:stackoverflow.com+python+float+exact&pbx=1&oq=site:stackoverflow.com+python+float+exact&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=3844l4441l1l4674l4l4l0l0l0l2l319l1070l2-3.1l4l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=4ea33f08981ef7d&biw=1153&bih=974

Comment: @MitchWheat Well, now this is the first result :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Floats use finite-precision binary encoding to represent numbers, so various operations lose some precision.

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) has a lot of information (maybe too much).

See also: [How do I use accurate float arithmetic in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563058/how-do-i-do-accurate-float-arithmetic-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Floating point arithmetic is not exact; there are rounding errors that are worsened by the fact that computers use binary floating point and not decimal floating point.  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding).