# Why is precision of decimal points different between multiplication and division of the same math statement?

Tags: python, math, decimal

```py
# Used "==" and "is" for equality
print(48 / 10 == 48 * 0.1)
print(48 / 10 is 48 * 0.1)
print()

# Check Both Answers Individually
print(f"48 / 10 = {48 / 10}")
print(f"48 * 0.1 = {48 * 0.1}")
```

In the following code, I thought both expressions would equal each other, but they do not. This is what it outputs.

```
False
False

48 / 10 = 4.8
48 * 0.1 = 4.800000000000001
```

Can someone explain why there is a difference in the result, whether you are using division or multiplication?

Comment: _# Used "==" and "is" for equality_ Don't use `is` for this, `==` is the correct way.

Comment: Its the difference between 1/10 and 0.1; it has nothing to do with the operation being used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Float Division Not Exact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120914/python-float-division-not-exact)

Comment: Also relevant: https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/floatingpoint.html.

Answer (score 1):

Even though multiplying by 0.1 and dividing by 10 are mathematically equal, in a computer program they are not.

When you write `0.1` in Python, what you get is not one tenth. It's slightly more. Here's `0.1` to 40 digits of precision:

```
>>> "%0.40f" % 0.1
'0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021182'
```

The difference is due to the fact that floating point numbers use a binary representation. You cannot represent 0.1 exactly with a finite number of binary digits, just like you can't represent 1/3 = 0.333333... exactly with a finite number of decimal digits.

Since `0.1` is slightly more than one tenth, you should expect `48*0.1` to be slightly more than 4.8. And it is:

```
>>> "%0.40f" % (48*0.1)
'4.8000000000000007105427357601001858711243'
```

You shouldn't expect `4.8` to equal 4.8 either. It's in fact slightly less than 4.8:

```
>>> "%0.40f" % (4.8)
'4.7999999999999998223643160599749535322189'
```